# How to return few function in one function? javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I sometimes repeat a few lines of code. Not to do that, I need to create a private function which returns all the following functions.

**All the functions are here:**

```
this.calculateCircleBarData();
this.calculateCircleBarDataActivities();
this.calculateCircleBarDataGibanja();
this.reduceTimeForAllTraining();
```

So I want to define a function to return all the functions above:

```
function whichReturnAllFunctions() {
    ...
    RETURN all function above
}
```

Comment: Why return all the functions as opposed to call a function that calls all those functions? You said it's repeated a few times; why repeat the code that calls the function that gets and calls those functions? Sounds like a case for a fluent api.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all functions as `callback function` value, then call it like below.

```js
var calculateCircleBarData = () => console.log("1");
var calculateCircleBarDataActivities = () => console.log("2");
var calculateCircleBarDataGibanja = () => console.log("3");
var reduceTimeForAllTraining = () => console.log("4");

function functionWichReturnAllFunction() {
      return [calculateCircleBarData, 
              calculateCircleBarDataActivities, 
              calculateCircleBarDataGibanja, 
              reduceTimeForAllTraining];
}

var allFunctions = functionWichReturnAllFunction();
for(let f of allFunctions)
  f(); // invoke the function from callback with ()
  
// You can also invoke the specific function by index like this
console.log('-------------');
allFunctions[0]();
```

Comment: @vagored61 Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help :)

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this is what you're looking for

```
functionWichReturnAllFunction() {
   const allFun = {
     circleBar: this.calculateCircleBarData.bind(this),
     circleBarActivities : this.calculateCircleBarDataActivities.bind(this),
     reduceTimeForAllTraining : this.reduceTimeForAllTraining.bind(this),
     circleBarGibanja : this.calculateCircleBarDataGibanja.bind(this),
   }
   return allFun;
}

const a = this.functionWichReturnAllFunction();
a.circleBar()
```

Comment: If the inside functions are not access `this` context, then you no need to `.bind(this)`, bro

Comment: anyway, `dictionary` with a more meaningful name (instead of `array` like me) makes sense to me, +1 ^^!

Comment: @MaiPhuong Thank you. `.bind` is used to create a reference to be used later. similar to how React bind methods in the constructor to the class properties. I'm binding the method it to the object properties and using the `this` context of the object.  You can take a look at this typescript playground I made to and review the logic I applied [playground](https://cutt.ly/kj5roAX)